# Powershell text editing

Tags: powershell

I've got a .bch file that i usually manually edit whenever I need to restore a database. The changes involve removing # from the start of specific lines and changing the database name of the lines where the # is removed to a new name that will be unique every time the script is run.

```
#DATABASE "YYYYY"
MOVE  "YYYYYY"
#TO  "H:\MSSQL.1\Data\YYYYY.mdf"
```

Change to

```
DATABASE "XXXXX"
MOVE  "YYYYYY"
TO  "H:\MSSQL.1\Data\XXXXX.mdf"
```

Would this be possible to do via a script in powershell?

Adding to question as I was pretty vague:

Hi Team, Sorry for the vague question I will get better as I ask more I'm sure. I'm aware of the replace function but in my research I couldn't really find anything to find specific characters. A function involving something like:

"On line Where character 1 from the left = # replace YYYY with XXX"

Then Step two of the shell script could be:

"on line Where string "XXXX" exists delete character 1 from the left"

I just can't find on google if functions like this exist

Comment: What have you tried so far?  if you show some effort, you're more likely to get help.

Comment: The case looks interesting but what is the actual  question? Looking to dinamically change the file name via Powershell? Have you tried something so far? Every bit of info helps.

Comment: Hi Team, Sorry for the vague question I will get better as I ask more I'm sure. I'm aware of the replace function but in my research I couldn't really find anything to find specific characters. A function involving something like 

"On line Where character 1 from the left = # replace YYYY with XXX"

Then Step two of the shell script could be:

"Where string "XXXX" exists delete character 1 from the left"

I just can't find on google if functions like this exist

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given much to go on, but have a start with:

cat somefile.bch | %{$_ -replace "expression","replace"} > newfile.bch